# How get object in Angular from Json?

Tags: angularjs

I do AJAX request on PHP server that returns me JSON object:

`lang: {news feed: "lenti"}`

When I do:

`$scope.data = response.data` and after try to display text from object in template:

```
{{data.lang.news feed}}
```

I get error in console.

Any Idea what is happening here?

Comment: `{{data.lang.news feed}}` is incorrect, there shouldn't be a space in there. This should be something like `{{data.lang.news.feed}}` or `{{data.lang.news_feed}}` and your JSON is also not correct. Entry should be something like  `{"lang": {"news_feed":"lenti"}}`

Comment: You should avoid spaces, but it would still work if you use quotes and use the bracket notation: `{{data.lang["news feed"]}}`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object should be `lang: {"news feed": "lenti"}`

So on UI you could access it by key

```
{{data.lang["news feed"]}}
```

Comment: @Hamed does it helped you or not?